# Assing variable from inner callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, async-await

**In my honest opinion this question is not duplicated because I know how to fix it using a callback as explain in the linked question, this question is specific about a situation where I cannot modify the outfer function and this is not covered in the another question**

I use a library that I cannot modify, the library do something like this:

`var result = Foo()`

Then it uses `result` for the work. I can not modify how `result` works, I can only modify `Foo` because I pass it as parameter to the library.

If `foo` has something like this

```
funcion Foo(){
  return "Hello"
}
```

It works perfect. Result is `Hello` and it works.

The issue is that my `Foo` has an async call inside it. It calls a web server and then it should return the response of the server. So

```
funcion Foo(){
   request.get('http://server.com', function(error, response, body){
      var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
      return parsed.Hello;
   });
}
```

In this case when `var result = Foo();`, `result` does not contains the response of the server (because is async) and continue with an empty result.

So if I only can modify `Foo` what should I do?

*Update: If you dont find it possible I would love to hear alternatives like what should I ask in PR for the library, or a way to force the request to be syncronous*

Comment: *>what should I ask in PR for the library* It would help if you described the module in more details.

Comment: Does the library accept a promise as the return value?

Comment: @SteveHansell I dont think so... This is where the library do that: (new_buf is result and filter is Foo in my explanation) https://github.com/chazomaticus/Haraka/blob/ece98e4797d78af9aad98c0469afde50bb9ba38d/mailbody.js#L255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can work with a synchronous request:

```
funcion Foo(){
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("GET", "http://server.com", false);
   request.send();
   function handleResponse(response) {
      console.log(response);
   }
   handleResponse(request.responseText);
}
```

If you can only modify `Foo`, then modify it to send the request synchronously.

Comment: two questions: 1. This is a Node.js app. Using sync calls will lock all execution of all users using it, or only the execution of the current user? If is only the current user I think I can accept it. 2. In Node.js not exist XMLHttpRequest so should i use this port https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest or are a better way to sync request in Node.js?

Comment: @RicardoPolo, 1. It should not block everyone, but it is safer to test it 2. Take a look at this library: https://github.com/coolaj86/futures

Comment: thank you! I will go with your option. I open another question to expand what I just comment to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503840/using-a-blocking-long-sync-operation-will-pause-all-users-in-node-js :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is impossible per se, once code is asynchronous, it can't be used as you would synchronous code. That's why [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) is a thing.

You could try to analyze the module internals and [monkey patch](http://johncoder.com/monkey-patching-in-node-js/) it, but that may not be possible depending on what exports the module exposes.

Comment: In this case, the solution is to modify Foo to send the request synchronously. Not a nice thing to do, but that is the solution, since the code using Foo expects Foo to work synchronously.

Comment: You are completely right, I totally forgot XMLHttpRequest had that option.